# Switch function in while loop only giving the same answer

Tags: java

I have a java switch function that is:

```
while(i < 1) {
    switch(hi) {
        case "Hi":                                                                      
        case "hi":                                    
        case "Hi!":                             
        case "hi!":                                  
        case "Hello!":                              
        case "hello!":                               
        case "Hello":                                
        case "hello":                 
            System.out.println("Hi!");
            break;    
        case "How are you?":
            x = Math.random() * Emotion.length;
            Feeling = (int)x;
            System.out.println(Emotion[Feeling] + " How are you?");
            break;
        default:
            break;
            
    } Hi.nextLine();
}
```

There are no errors in debug, but the output is this:

"Me: Hi,
Computer: Hi!,
Me: How are you?,
Computer: Hi!,"
How do I make it so I can use switch loop many times without getting the same result every time?

All help would be appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to assign `hi` again. A [mcve] would help.

Comment: When this loop iterates, where do you ever update the value of `hi`?  Why do you expect that value to change?

Comment: I just tried adding "Hi = new Scanner(System.in);" in before the Hi.nextLine. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @PollySmith225: `Hi` and `hi` are two different variables.  Assigning one does nothing to the other.  Where do you ever assign any value to `hi` at all?

Comment: Include the code where you are populating the variable `hi` (consider renaming this to `input` or something like that since it clearly is not limited to being "hi").  What is while-loop and `i` variable supposed to be doing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you assign the `hi` variable before the loop, and never re-assign it later. You should assign the value of `Hi.nextLine();` to `hi` within the loop as follows:

```java
hi = Hi.nextLine();
```